# Are expansion sets in magic designed for use with specific deck archetypes?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I'm new to Magic so apologies in advance if this is an obvious question: Are expansion sets designed to accommodate any/all deck archetypes?

For example, my current play style gravitates towards red aggro and I'd like to continue building decks that align with that strategy.  I'm wondering if the latest set, *Journey Into Nyx*, is slanted towards other play styles. How can I tell?

Comment: Journey hardly changed the current meta-game at all (although Mana Confluence did allow people to squash cards that were already good in their respective decks into one deck). We still have two more sets to go before we see a fresh meta. Will Red Aggro still be viable at that point? The answer is purely speculation. [MTG Salvation](http://www.mtgsalvation.com/) welcomes speculation, and I'm sure you would have a more enjoyable back and forth in that setting. I also recommend [TappedOut](http://tappedout.net/) for getting feedback on a particular deck.

Comment: Pointing you to all of these other places is my way of helping you before I vote to close your question as Primarily opinion-based.

Comment: @Rusher It sounds like you may be misreading his question a bit. He's not asking "will my red aggro deck still be competitive when the next set is released?" He's asking if different MTG sets tend to be designed to favor some deck types over others; which is a question that can be objectively answered.

Comment: @GendoIkari Well, I disagree. I believe he was asking if certain sets favor specific archetypes so that he could use that information to determine how viable his Red Aggro deck will be in the future. I also disagree that the question as you read it is objectively answerable. Mark Rosewater may tell you that Theros was designed to push a Two-Color Midrange archetype, but you might argue that it favored Red Deck Wins, and I may argue that it really strengthened Control.

Comment: @Gendolkari That said, if someone finds a credible article with convincing statistics that says that the first expansion of every block has favored a specific archetype X% of the time, then I concede my point.

Comment: @Rusher If you haven't already, I would encourage you to read [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/). Beyond that, the OP definitely asked a question with both a general form and a specific example form, and is probably in the best position to clarify his intent, rather than letting us second-guess.

Comment: @Jefromi The Board and Card Game community is plagued by users who have sorely misinterpreted the contents of that article and now apply it in such a way that nearly *any* question can be salvaged. This question simply begs for confirmation bias. Answers will be looking to confirm the patterns that they *think* they see. I don't think that the question adds value to the site because it almost certainly will not be useful in making predictions or even determining where the Journey into Nyx meta-game will be two weeks from now.

Comment: @Rusher I am not trying to make a definitive statement about this question. I am trying to (1) stop people from saying that questions are off-topic purely because they're subjective (the community here is plagued by people who do that), and (2) stop people from putting words in the OP's mouth.

Comment: @Jefromi I didn't vote to close the question because it was off-topic. I voted to close because the question it is primarily opinion-based. There is already one answer claiming that Red Deck Wins is nearly always "efficient". I might disagree. Red aggro decks are notoriously cheap to build and carry the illusion of being easy to pilot, and so they sneak into competitive play whether they are viable or not. The point is that I might disagree with the diagnosis of that answer and could provide my own dissenting answer, but it's all just *noise*.

Comment: @Rusher I don't know what you're trying to convince me of, again, I'm not trying to say that much about this specific question. Re-read my last comment, and find me in chat or on meta if you want to discuss something.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15092/discussion-between-rusher-and-jefromi).

Comment: Hi all.  I'm really sorry if my prior question was confusing.  It was indeed asking "if different MTG sets tend to be designed to favor some deck types over others".  The question is answered below so I'll mark it as answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most sets of Magic feature a certain kind of game mechanics, and favor some archetypes more than other.

For instance the previous set (Return to Ravnica, Gatecrash, Maze I don't remember) favored multicolored decks, even 3 colored ones, featured lots of multicolored creatures, whereas the beginning of the current set (Theros, Born of the gods) favored mono colored decks. Some capacity are absent from different sets, and some sets really favor some kind of build (eg Theros set gave the opportunity to create really powerful blue aggro, Innistrad set allowed very efficient graveyard oriented decks...).

Nevertheless, some archetypes are always valids, and even if some blocks don't favor them, you will still find useful cards and maybe the next set will favor it again. Some archetypes are also more common and nearly always efficient, "red deck wins", a mono red archetype is among them.

If you don't care about having a deck in the current set, you shouldn't mind about this, if you seek competitive T2 game (last two blocks), you will change deck every block to have the more favored (and fun) archetype. An easy way to see toward what a set is slanted is to have a look at the top 10 tournament decks, you can also guess that by yourself after gaining some more experience by just looking at the cards featured.

To finish, if you play drafts (which I advise you, it's really funny), the favored archetypes will be different from built decks.